# Нет wi-fi подключения в основной машине после запуска виртуальной

Tags: linux, wifi, virtualbox

До подключения к Kali Linux через VM, интернет на основной oc есть,  но как только запускаю дочернюю систему сразу пропадает сигнал на основной. На кали всё работает. Тим подключения сетевой мост. После запуска виртуалки винда перестаёт видеть сетевую карту. Где не смотрел ничего не помогало, с ubuntu такая же херь, видимо дело в VM. Если что-то нужно узнать, пишите, отвечу быстро. При запуске VM звучит звук отключения в винде.

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам, создал виртуальную сеть хоста VM. Через винду сделал мост с этим адаптером и своей wifi сетью, в настройках usb конкретной виртуальной машины убрал свой wifi адаптер. Теперь linux как бы подключен к своей виртуальной сети, которая в свою очередь соединена мостом с wifi. Так и знал что ответ где-то на поверхности, может чайникам вроде меня понадобиться, в индийских гайдах такое не показывали

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).